# "economic future" vs. "future economy"

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

Consider these

> The high-tech industry does matter to our **economic future**.
>
> The high-tech industry does matter to our **future economy**.

Do they mean the same thing? Are they both correct?

Comment: Did you make them yourself? If so, what do you want to convey? An economic future and the future of our economy can mean two different things, generally speaking. Though the first sentence does not look familiar to me. I am a learner though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The high-tech industry does matter to our economic future. = The high-tech industry will **specifically/especially** affect our economy in the future.
>
> The high-tech industry does matter to our future economy. = The high-tech industry will affect our economy in the future.

IMO, first implies that the speaker is particularly concerned about economy and that his/her prediction of the future is solely focused on its economic aspect.
The second implies that the speaker is concerned about the future, and in this instance is talking about the economic aspect of it.

Specifically, the two emphasize different things:

> **economic future** = big umbrella is economy, small umbrella is the future
>
> **future economy** = big umbrella is future, small umbrella is the economy

Although, I could be wrong since I'm also a learner. Take my answer with a grain or two of salt.

Comment: IMO, by the ehe expressions 'economic future" or "future economy" , the speaker expresses his concern for economy, the trade and industry of his country, in future.